# Setting up an Minimizing the sum of absolute deviation linear programing problem in CPlex

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

I am new to CPLEx and trying to set up my first problem. What I want to do set up a LP to minimise the sum of absolute deviations. I have set up the below as a start (based on googling possibilities). This is only a single deviation. I thought I would get this to work and then add to ti. It loads ok but won't solve. Can anyone shed some light on where I need to go next?

```
Minimize
 obj: y1pos + y1neg
Subject To
 c1: x0 + x1 + x2 + x3 = 1
 c2: y1pos - y1neg + 451320 x0 + 500870 x1 + 483425 x2 + 447330 x3 = 58999
Bounds
 0 <= x0 <= 1
 0 <= x1 <= 1
 0 <= x2 <= 1
 0 <= x3 <= 1
 y1pos >= 0
 y1neg <= 0
End
```

Comment: Try `y1neg >= 0` instead of `y1neg <= 0`.

Comment: Ahh - thats it - of course. Thank you very much

Comment: @Stewart_Fischer: since you have figured out the issue, it would be helpful for others if you [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This helps folks know that your question has been answered and resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As Erwin Kalvelagen suggested, changing `y1neg <= 0` to `y1neg >= 0` was the answer since our our error factor in our constraint is `y1pos - y1neg` which we want to minimise.